# A good Design Reference and advice for object oriented design of a CRM

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net

I searched codeplex and google. I have found so many such as tustena but unfortunately they are not domain driven based and in these solutions I could not find a good modelling documents or references.
i am a newbie in CRM but I am sensetive to design it with solid object-oriented fundamentals. Any reference or open source solution especifically for CRM design and implementaion in .NET? Cheers

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for a book then "Working with Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011" by Sonoma Partners is a great reference - [http://www.amazon.com/Working-Microsoft-Dynamics%C2%AE-CRM-2011/dp/0735648123](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735648123)

My personal go to reference is the CRM 2011 SDK, which has quite a few examples and there is a page that is devoted to best practices. - http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=420f0f05-c226-4194-b7e1-f23ceaa83b69